# How do you avoid Rake task name conflict for dependencies?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

```
namespace :jobs do
  task :environment => [:environment] do
    #Something cool
  end
end
```

This causes a **circular dependency** on `:environment`, which I am just trying to depend on the Rails task `environment`.

How can this be correctly setup?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to append some code to the built in :environment task? Or did you just really want to name your custom task :environment? If the latter, then just name it something else.

Comment: I really want to name my task :environment and renaming it does not answer the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should also be able to say:

```
task :environment => [ 'rake:environment' ] do ... end
```

The 'rake:' namespace is the top level namespace.  It's like doing ::CONSTANT_NAME in ruby.

Answer (score 5):

I have just had exactly the same issue, where a task in a namespace is trying to call a task of the same name in the parent namespace.  This is indeed possible.

```
namespace :jobs do
  task :environment => [ '^environment' ] do
    #Something cool
  end
end
```

Each caret you use will begin name resolution one level higher in the namespace hierarchy.  See: http://rake.rubyforge.org/files/doc/rakefile_rdoc.html